# Programmatically add new Datagrid (or other UserControll) into a programmatically generated TabItem (using mvvm)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have an XAML-Code with an TabControl that contains 2 tabs (Tab A and Tab B). In Tab A I can make configurations for Tab B, Tab B can therefore change dynamically in dependency to Tab A. Tab B contains a static Tabcontroll without any tabs implemented (beqause tabs will be generated later). Notice: "Tab A" and "Tab B" are the Master Tabs, "Tab C", "Tab D", and so on are the child Tabs from "Tab B".

This is My XAML Code:

```
<TabItem Header="TAB_B">
            <Grid>
                <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyTabItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <!-- here I want to show a Datagrid for each new Tab ("Tab C", "Tab D", ...) -->
                            </DataTemplate>                            
                        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                </TabControl>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
```

In my ViewModel I have the binding property:

```
    private ObservableCollection<TabItem> _myTabItems;
    public ObservableCollection<TabItem> MyTabItems
    {
        get { return _myTabItems; }
        set
        {
            _myTabItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyTabItems");
        }
    }
```

In my Viewmodel a have a method that builds my Tab Items in the TabController in Tab B:

```
    public void BuildContentOfTabB()
    {
        foreach (var item in myTabList)
        {
                MyTab = new TabItem();
                MyTab.Header = myHeaderString; // e.g. "Tab C", "Tab D"
                MyTabItems.Add(MyTab);
            }
        }
    }
```

This works well. I get new TabItems ("Tab C", "Tab D",...) in my TabController. Now I want to get new UserControlls like a Datagrid in "Tab C" or "Tab D". I don't have any idea how to solve my problem. Thank you for answering.

Comment: set `<TabControl.ContentTemplate>` to your `TabControl`. `MyTabItems` should be `ObservableCollection<MyClass>`

Comment: If your "viewmodel" contains anything view specific (like `TabItem`), this is not MVVM. In MVVM, the VM layer is not directly coupled to a specific view technology.

Comment: @grek40: but how can i solve this problem whitout damaging my MVVM pattern?

Comment: @rmbq: thank you, but with TabControl.ItemTemplate i get in every tab the same content. I need in every tab other contents. How can i solve this?

Comment: Can you be more specific about how *different* the contents of Tab B/C/D actually are? Different solutions are possible for similar contents vs. completely unrelated contents.

Comment: Tab B is a Master Tab. It contains a Tabcontainer with variable Tabs (C, D, E,...). the user controlls in tab C, D... will be the same. But they should bind to other objects and sould show different values. I need 4 buttuns and 2 datagrids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a base class for your viewmodels:

```
public abstract class BaseVM {}
```

than modify your `MyTabItem` property:

```
public ObservableCollection<BaseVM> MyTabItems...
```

create your custom viewmodels inherits from `BaseVM` (`public class DatagridVM:BaseVM`)
your tabControl is:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyTabItems}">
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

in your ResourceDictionary define the view of your viewmodels:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DatagridVM}">
    <Datagrid/>
</DataTemplate>
```